# How to get objectID of object in database

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I need the String representation of the ID of an object that is in my Mongo.

```
    QuestionDTO questionDTO = new QuestionDTO ();
    HashMap<String, QuestionDTO > nodes = new HashMap<>();
    nodes.put("foo", QuestionDTO );

    Rule rule = new Rule("my rule", nodes);
    ruleRepository.save(rule);
```

ObjectId.toString() will do the job. I can open the Mongo shell and find the rule object id  but how do I get the ObjectId in java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing ruleRepository is an implementation of [MongoRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html), save method returns your entity, with generated _id. So update your code to get returned object, as advised in [the save method description](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-) :

#### Add id field to Rule object :

```
@Id
@JsonProperty
private String id;
@JsonProperty
private String name;
@JsonProperty
private String cat;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

#### Update your code :

```
QuestionDTO questionDTO = new QuestionDTO ();
HashMap<String, QuestionDTO > nodes = new HashMap<>();
nodes.put("foo", QuestionDTO );
Rule rule = new Rule("my rule", nodes);
rule= ruleRepository.save(rule);  //Note the variable re-assignement
String id = rule.getId();
```